# is it possible to combine unknown format file to jar file

Tags: java, serialization, jar

i have developed a project in java using swings and mysql. now in order to assign security to the project i want to store the Registration key in an unknown file format like .xyz using serialization. the key entered by the user is compared with the key stored in .xyz file. now, is it possible to add my .xyz file with jar file? if yes how is it possible? please help me to complete the project. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jar file is just a zip file. You can add there as many files of any type as you want. 
I do not know how your project is organized. If you do not use maven or gradle you probably have to add your file to `src` folder. If you do use maven add it to `resources` folder.

Comment: I've used netbeans to develop the project and jar file. so will it work if i copy the file to src folder? Thanks for the reply.